# Can't find or load main class com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator

Tags: codenameone

When running the command

`java -cp dist/A1Prj.jar:JavaSE.jar com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator com.mycompany.a1.Starter`

while inside my project directory, I'm greeted with the error

`Error: Could not find or load main class com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator`

My application runs fine from eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is on Windows you need to replace the `:` with `;` which is the right path separator for Windows.

Notice that the last argument is no longer used, we now use the main class defined in the `codenameone_settings.properties` file.

Comment: Now I'm getting `JavaSE.jar: The term 'JavaSE.jar' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function...`

Comment: Okay, I feel silly, but the issue was I was using Powershell and not command prompt. Once I realized this, I switched over and it worked fine. Thanks for the help.